# Power Bi - issue with if measure

Tags: excel, powerbi

Really appreciate your help with this ! I am trying to analyze some data in power bi and this is how the data is current displayed ( just an example )

Table look like this :
I am not allowed to post a pic but i hope this understand ( bold is header and the rest is the content )

***1)Company      2)No of error      3)No of time to be used***

A                  1                 3

A                  4                 1

B                  1                 2

B                  1                 2

C                  0                 1

I want the table to change into this :

***1)Company      2)No of error      3)No of time to be used***

A                  0                 1

B                  0                 1

C                  1                 1

So to explain this : so it sums what is for the same company and if the eroors are >1 then will display 0 otherwise will be 1 . For how many time is used it's the other way , if it's been used once it will 1 otherwise 0.

The purpose for this will be to calculate for a speacific period : No of errors/ no of time used *100. ( so it will count how many 1s have been in that period and do the maths )

I have used an if measure but it doesn't help as i can't count ifs ( not sure if it makes sense )

Thanks a lottt! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Please try this code:

You need to create "New Table" command,then paste the code:

Full DAX Code:

```
NewTable =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    VALUES ( YourTable[Company] ),
    "Test1", CALCULATE ( IF ( SUM ( YourTable[No of error] ) > 1, 0, 1 ) ),
    "Test2", CALCULATE ( IF ( COUNT ( YourTable[Company] ) >= 1, 1, 0 ) )
)
```

If we test it,

[image: FRS]

Comment: Pleasure! I am pleased to help @GeorgianaPislaru. Stay Safe!